# When Promisifying a XMLHttpRequest, how to catch a throw Error

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, promise

After I've Promisified my XMLHttpRequest, like so:

```
var Request = (function() {
var get = function(url){
    return request('GET', url);
  },
  post = function(url){
    return request('POST', url);
  },
  request = function(method, url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url);
      xhr.onload = function(e){
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          resolve(xhr);
        } else {
          reject(Error('XMLHttpRequest failed; error code:' + xhr.statusText));
        }
      },
      xhr.onerror = reject;
      xhr.send();
    });
  };

  return {
    get: get,
    post: post,
    request: request
  }
})();
```

I'd like to catch all network related errors, which this snippet already does. Now, when I chain my `.then` calls when the XHR calls are finished, I can pass around the result of the Ajax call.

**Here is my question:**

When I throw an `Error` in any `.then` branch, it will not get caught by the `catch` clause.

How can I achieve this?

Note that the `throw new Error("throw error");` will not be caught in the catch clause....

For the entire code, see http://elgervanboxtel.nl/site/blog/xmlhttprequest-extended-with-promises

Here is my example code:

```
Request.get( window.location.href ) // make a request to the current page
.then(function (e) {

 return e.response.length;

})
.then(function (responseLength) {

  // log response length
  console.info(responseLength);

  // throw an error
  throw new Error("throw error");

})
.catch(function(e) { // e.target will have the original XHR object

  console.log(e.type, "readystate:", e.target.readyState, e);

});
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. I am getting `error readystate: 4 XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent {}`

Comment: My bad... That is because you cannot do a ajax request to google.com.

But you can do a request to the same page as you're on... Let me change the code in my question...

As you can see now, the length of the response has been written to console, but there is no trace of the error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the error gets thrown before your `then` block gets called.

### Solution

```
Request
  .get('http://google.com')
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('XHR ERROR:', error);
  })
  .then(function(responseLength) {
    // log response length
    console.info(responseLength);
    // throw an error
    throw new Error("throw error");
  })
  .catch(function(error) { 
    // e.target will have the original XHR object
    console.error('SOME OTHER ERROR', error);
  });
```

### Hint

Why are you not using [`fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)?

Comment: Tnx @HaNdTriX, I'm not using fetch because of browser support. See: [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch)